# Ruby real time google analytics API

Tags: ruby, google-analytics, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to get activeVisitors with the google-api-ruby-client. The client is listed in the real time google analytics API docs [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/libraries) however I see nothing in the docs about using it for real time api.

I see the function discovered_api however I see no list for posisble parameters for the API name.

Example for Regular Analytics API:

```
# Get the analytics API
analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3')
```

Does anyone know how to use this client to get real time active visitors?

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'

# Update these to match your own apps credentials
service_account_email = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com' # Email of service account
key_file = '/path/to/key/privatekey.p12' # File containing your private key
key_secret = 'notasecret' # Password to unlock private key
profileID = '111111111' # Analytics profile ID.

# Get the Google API client
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => '[YOUR APPLICATION NAME]',
:application_version => '0.01')

# Load your credentials for the service account
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
:token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
:issuer => service_account_email,
:signing_key => key)

# Start the scheduler
SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do

# Request a token for our service account
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

# Get the analytics API
analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3')

# Execute the query
visitCount = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => {
'ids' => "ga:" + profileID,
'metrics' => "ga:activeVisitors",
})

# Update the dashboard
send_event('current_visitors', { current: visitCount.data.rows[0][0] })
end
```

Error returned:

```
Missing required parameters: end-date, start-date.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the ruby client lib uses the discovery service and the method is actually available, instead of:

```
visitCount = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => {
'ids' => "ga:" + profileID,
'metrics' => "ga:activeVisitors",
```

try this (change ga to realtime in the api_method):

```
visitCount = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.realtime.get, :parameters => {
'ids' => "ga:" + profileID,
'metrics' => "ga:activeVisitors",
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're a member of the Real-time reporting product forum, this post may be helpful - https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-analytics-realtime-api/zgAsKFBenV8

You might try...

analytics = client.discovered_api('realtime','v3')

Or real-time, or w/o v3.

If that works update your get method too.

Wish I could be more help but there is absolutely no documentation on this.

Comment: Still no luck trying your suggestions. How does one get invited to that google group?

Comment: Should have been invited when you were accepted to the beta. You should be able to request access if you do have beta account. Best of luck!