# ruby: how to get count vistor a page with google analytics

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, google-analytics-api

i want to count visitor by page

```
opts = YAML.load_file("ga_config.yml")

## Update these to match your own apps credentials in the ga_config.yml file
service_account_email = opts['service_account_email']  # Email of service account
key_file = opts['key_file']                            # File containing your private key
key_secret = opts['key_secret']                        # Password to unlock private key
profile_id = opts['profileID'].to_s                    # Analytics profile ID.


client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => opts['application_name'],
  :application_version => opts['application_version'])

## Load our credentials for the service account
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)

visitors = []


client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
  :issuer => service_account_email,
  :signing_key => key)

# Start the scheduler

  # Request a token for our service account
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

  # Get the analytics API
  analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3')

  # Execute the query
  response = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.realtime.get, :parameters => {
    'ids' => "ga:" + profile_id,
    'metrics' => "ga:activeVisitors",
  })

  puts response.data.rows.count
```

when in run code. 
response.data.row.count = 0.
but i go to https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#realtime/rt-content

in content

> Right Now : 2

apparently there are any mistakes in my code?
how to fix this?

and I want to display get visitor by page
example:

```
ActivePage                         activeUser
/page1                                  1
/page2                                  3
```

How to get above data ?

thanks

Comment: ga:activeVisitors isn't even a valid metric.  I am really surprised that request works.

Comment: i read and follow the instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189610/ruby-real-time-google-analytics-api

how t fix error?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do are you trying to access real-time data or not.    That tutorial uses analytics.data.ga.get you use  analytics.data.realtime.get

Comment: so , you can guide me get data realtime from google analytics use ruby ?

Comment: Not much I am not a ruby developer.   but I would start by sending Realtime dimensiosn and metrics   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

Comment: wild guess 'metrics' => "rt:activeVisitors",
'dimensions' => "rt:pagePath",

Comment: ok tks :D
u save my life

Answer (score 1):

you are requesting data from the Real-time api but you are not using valid real-time api metric.  You will also need to add a dimension

try this

```
'metrics' => "rt:activeVisitors", 'dimensions' => "rt:pagePath",
```

Comment: `response = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.realtime.get, :parameters => {
    'ids' => "ga:" + profile_id,
    'metrics' => "rt:activeUsers",
    'dimensions' => "rt:pagePath",
  }) `

or 

`'metrics' => "rt:activeVisitors", 'dimensions' => "rt:pagePath", `
both dont working.
how to use valid real-time api matric?.

Comment: in link :  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/
i dont find metrics  = "rt:activeVisitors", only  'metrics' => "rt:activeUsers"

Comment: tks, i have done it :D. 
`reult = [["/t/danh-muc/dong-ho-nam", "1"],["/t/danh-muc/dong-ho-nu", "1"]]`

 Now. i want to filter by pagePath, when pagePath contain a `string ='dong-ho-nam'` result can is : 

reult = [["/t/danh-muc/dong-ho-nam", "1"]] i use `filter =>''rt:pagePath==*dong-ho-nam*''` but don't working. I should be written what thing in filters –